# What is the definition of 1 standard deviation.

Tags: statistics

I know what the standard deviation is. I know about the 68–95–99.7. My question is what is the definition of 1 (just 1) standard deviation. Why is it 68 and not 70. Is it because that's where the inflection points on the curve are?

Comment: Can anyone is able to understand that : " I know about the 68–95–99.7"; "what is the definition of 1 (just 1) standard deviation. Why is it 68 and not 70." ? **Is it an aliens code ?**

Comment: It is the square root of the variance. Standard deviation is defined for all distributions (possibly infinite).

Comment: If you have a random variable that has mean and variance "1 standard deviation" just means the length $1\sigma$ or just $\sigma$, where $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. In the context of that 68-95-99.7 rule, this number is used to measure the radius of an interval around the mean value. The rule says that if the random variable is normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$, then the probability that the random variable gives a value in the interval $[\mu-\sigma,\mu+\sigma]$ (this is, a value within $\sigma$ from $\mu$) is approximately $0.68$.

Comment: @Surb He's referring to the empirical rule for standard deviations. Meaning that in a normal distribution around 68% of the data points are within 1 standard deviation, about 95% are within 2 standard deviations and about 99.7% within 3 standard deviations. He then asks why 68% are within 1 standard deviation and not 70%.

Comment: Why $68$ and not $70$?  Because it comes about when talking about [$\int\limits_{-1}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx = \text{erf}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\approx 0.682689$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+from+-1+to+1+of+e%5E%28-x%5E2%2F2%29%2Fsqrt%282pi%29), the area under the curve of the [standard normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) over the interval $-1$ to $1$.  The other values corresponding to if the limits on the integral ranged from $-2$ to $2$ or from $-3$ to $3$ respectively.

Comment: Superb answers! Now I understand what it is instead of just how to use it. Thank you so much JMoravitz, lepidon, jack-pfaffinger.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!
You have to keep in mind that the normal standard distribution $N(0,1)$ is always our golden standard for various reasons. In this case mean is $0$ and variance is 1.

If the random variable takes values for example in meters, variance is not that useful in understand how much it can change since it is in squared meters, on the other hand s.d. is in flat meters giving us some understanding on what is going on.

For $N(0,1)$ the standard deviation is $1$ as well. We are interested in how common it is to be at distance less than 1 from the mean $0$, so we compute $$\mathbb P (|N(0,1)|<1 ) \simeq 0.6827$$ as you can check [here](http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html) using "between -1 and 1". You can calculate "between -2 and 2" and "between -3 and 3", you will find probabilities $0.9545$ and $0.9973$. Basically almost every extraction from $N(0,1)$ stands in the range of $3$ standard deviations from the mean $0$, because $$\mathbb P (|N(0,1)|< 3 ) \simeq 0.9973.$$